# Exit code 11 on extractMin() in PriorityQueue in C'99

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, heap, priority-queue

I'm new in C programming. I'm developing a priority queue in C'99 with the heap data structure.

I'm using *heapifyDown()* in combination with *swapValues()* to sort the heap array for extracting the first element (min-heap) *pqueue_extractMin()* function. My structure looks like this:

```
typedef struct ProrityQueue_s PriorityQueue; 
typedef struct PriorityQueue_Entry_s *PriorityQueue_Entry;

struct ProrityQueue_s {
    int size, last;
    char error;
    PriorityQueue_Entry *entries;
};

struct PriorityQueue_Entry_s {
    char *value;
    float priority;
};
```

**For information – Full code for information on gist: https://gist.github.com/it4need/ddf9014bfda9fe6a64bb01a7417422bc**

**Questions:**

1. Insertion into the Priority queue ("minheap") looks good. Everything is fine. But when I'm extract more than one element at once, I will get this error: "Process finished with exit code 11".
2. Is this line allowed to copy the whole contents of the last element to the first of the heap? `priorityqueue->entries[0] = priorityqueue->entries[priorityqueue->last];`
3. `swapValues(priorityqueue, currentPositionIndex, smallestChild);` Can I swap values of whole Structure elements? -> implementation (bottom).

**HeapifyDown():**

```
void heapifyDown(PriorityQueue *priorityqueue)
{
    int currentPositionIndex = 0;

    while(currentPositionIndex < priorityqueue->last)
    {
        int smallestChild = currentPositionIndex;

        int leftChildIndex = (2 * currentPositionIndex) + 1;
        int rightChildIndex = (2 * currentPositionIndex) + 2;

        smallestChild = (priorityqueue->entries[leftChildIndex]->priority < priorityqueue->entries[smallestChild]->priority && priorityqueue->last > leftChildIndex)
                        ? leftChildIndex : smallestChild;

        smallestChild = (priorityqueue->entries[rightChildIndex]->priority < priorityqueue->entries[smallestChild]->priority && priorityqueue->last > rightChildIndex)
                        ? rightChildIndex : smallestChild;

        if(smallestChild == currentPositionIndex)
        {
            break;
        }

        swapValues(priorityqueue, currentPositionIndex, smallestChild);  // @todo: Why does this line break the function on two function calls by negative values
        currentPositionIndex = smallestChild;
    }
}
```

**SwapValues():**

```
void swapValues(PriorityQueue *priorityqueue, int firstIndex, int secondIndex)
{
    // @todo: Does this work properly?
    PriorityQueue_Entry tmp_entry = priorityqueue->entries[firstIndex];
    priorityqueue->entries[firstIndex] = priorityqueue->entries[secondIndex];
    priorityqueue->entries[secondIndex] = tmp_entry;
}
```

**extractMin():**

```
char *pqueue_extractMin(PriorityQueue *priorityqueue)
{
    if(isEmpty(priorityqueue))
    {
        priorityqueue->error = ERROR_PRIORITY_QUEUE_EMPTY;
    }

    priorityqueue->last--;

    char *tmp = priorityqueue->entries[0]->value;
    priorityqueue->entries[0] = priorityqueue->entries[priorityqueue->last]; // @todo: Is this allowed?

    heapifyDown(priorityqueue); // @todo: Why does this line break the extractMin() function on two function calls -> check swapValues() in heapifyDown()

    return tmp;
}
```

Full code for information on gist: https://gist.github.com/it4need/ddf9014bfda9fe6a64bb01a7417422bc

Comment: Your child subscripting dereference should NOT happen if a child is outside the range of the number of elements in your queue. Ex: if a queue has four elements, then slot-0 has children at 1,2, and slot-1 has a *single* child at 3; there is no second child for slot-1, and slot-2 has *no* children. In short, it can be (and is) more complicated than just calculating child indexes and going nuts with them.

Comment: ""Process finished with exit code 11" The way to debug such issues is to use a debugger. It will tell you almost immediately exactly which line of code triggers the exit and allows you to examine the state of the program as it runs. Learn to use a debugger effectively - it will be well worth your time.